# An exercise about vector multiplication/scalar product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, vectors

I came across an exercise in vector multiplication but couldn’t find the formal answer for it to check myself.

I would really appreciate if someone could show me the correct answer for this exercise.

the exercise is as follows:

Let $v = (1, 2, 2)$ be a vector
From all the possible unit vectors $u$ one was chosen such as $|v + u|$ is at its maximum value.
Thus the scalar product of $v \cdot u$ is equal to:

1. $3$
2. $1$
3. $0$
4. $-3$
5. $-1$

I’ve tried solving the exercise but I am not sure if my reasoning was indeed right. What I’ve tried is:

If I’m not mistaken the sum of two vectors gives a total vector which is, at most, as long as the combined length of the other two vectors:

Basically $|u + v| \leq |u|$ + $|v|$

From this I conquered that if |u + v| is at its maximum value then $|u + v| = |u| + |v|$ which implies that both vector $v$ and vector $u$ “point” to the same direction.

The scalar product is equal to $|u||v|\cos(\text{deg between})$ which is equal to $3 \cdot 1 \cdot \cos(0) = 3$, which was my final answer.

Because the source of the exercise didn’t have an answer, I would really appreciate if someone could show me the proper way to solve it in case I did a mistake.

Comment: Welcome. We would really appreciate it if you showed your thoughts and your own attempts, otherwise our giving of a correct answer will not really help you, in the long-term educational sense. There is also a courtesy related to the effort ratio - users are less interested in putting effort into a clear, well-explained answer if the question itself does not contain effort

Comment: Post edit:  what you wrote looks good. To maximize $|\vec v+\vec u|$ take $\vec u=\frac {\vec v}{|\vec v|}$.  Then $\vec v\cdot \vec u = |\vec v|=3$, just as you claimed.